# How to implement Google Voice type telephony registration feature in .NET?

Tags: .net, api, telephony, gateway

When you register a phone number with your google voice account google voice calls the number you just registered and you get the pin code used to confirm that it is indeed your phone you are trying to register, and to finish the registration process.

How would you go about implementing this feature in .NET?

Specifically, when my user enters the phone number and hits the button I would like my IIS server to somehow dial that number and deliver the voice message with the pin code to the user...

If this is not possible or I would need a dedicated telephony server, are there any telephony gateway providers that have a .NET api I can use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check out the service [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/).  They have a dead easy API for that stuff.  Check it out.

Comment: Looks a lot better than what I was suggesting.

Comment: That looks like exactly what I need and they do have a C# helper library. I'm still hoping to get some answers on how could this be accomplished without using an outside vendor like Twilio...

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the [Speech SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721044.aspx) for speaking out the message of the call and parsing the [DTMF tones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-tone_multi-frequency_signaling), but you will still need a library to actually make the call. Most likely you will need a [SIP provider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol) and a library to make calls from your code with it.

Unfortunately I have not worked with any SIP libraries so I can not give you a recommendation.